# Refactoring my database schema

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm refactoring my current schema and it's too abstract for me.

I monitor my servers with a homemade monitoring software. This software sends HTTP requests to a Rails web server with about ten different fields worth of information so I can get a quick overview of everything.

My current implementation:

```
server [id, name, created_date, edited_date, ..., etc ]
status_update [id, server_id, field1, field2, field3, created_date, edited_date, ..., etc]
```

I treat the servers as Users and status updates as Tweets. I delete any status_update on a server_id older than the tenth one just to keep from growing to infinity.

Though I'm starting to run into a few complications. I need to display information from the most recent status_update on the index page, I need to sort the servers based on status_update info, I need to store info from certain status_updates that may be way older than 10 status_updates old. It also seems like I'm going to start needing to store information from status_updates in both the server and status_update, which would cause hitting the DB multiple times on an insert. Thus, I am looking to refactor.

My requirements:
I only need to display information from the most recent update.
Having the next 9 status_updates helps debug if the system goes offline.
I need to be able to sort based on some info from most recent status_update.
I need the database to remain small (Heroku free).
Ideal performance, IE not hitting database more than once unless necessary.
Non-Complicated DB structure so I can pass it along.

**Edit: Additional Info** => I am looking to ultimately monitor about 150-200 servers (a lot for a hobby dev, but I'm cheap). Each monitoring service posts every five minutes or so unless something goes wrong. So, worst case scenario has me reaching max capacity every four hours.

I was thinking it would be nice to track when the last time X event happened, and what the result was. Thus, tracking that information would have to be moved to the `server` model itself since I'm wiping out old records and would lose the information after an hour or so. Though in retrospect, I could just save that info in memory using the monitoring service and send it up every five minutes or only once each time it changes. I could also simply edit that information only when it changes, so as to process less information on each request. Hm!

Comment: It seems to me like everything you want to do can be done using your current structure. I don't see a compelling reason to refactor. What's the most serious problem *you* see here?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' The query got so complicated that I needed to access the data VIA SQL instead of Active Record. While that isn't the end of the world, I would prefer being able to use AR over SQL in Rails. I also need to store some data longer than the 10 `update_status` records I'm saving, so I suspect I'll have to save it in a field in the `server` model. I just feel as though it's inefficient to hit the DB twice on a single post to the server. Am I just thinking too much into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Efficiency**

All ORMs, including ActiveRecord, are designed and built around certain tradeoffs. It's commonplace for ORMs to use several simple SELECT statements to do what a SQL developer would do with a single SELECT statement. You're probably not overwhelming Heroku with your queries.

There's no reasonable structural solution to this problem.

**Size**

Your "status_update" table should be able to hold an enormous number of rows. Heroku's hobby-dev plan allows 10,000 rows.  How many servers do you seriously expect to monitor on a free plan?  If I were you, I would delete old rows from it no more than once a day, or when I got a permission error. (On Heroku, certain permission errors mean you're over the row limit.)

> It also seems like I'm going to start needing to store information
>   from status_updates in both the server and status_update, which would
>   cause hitting the DB multiple times on an insert.

This really makes little sense.  Tweets don't require updates to the user account; status updates don't require updates about the server. *This* might suggest refactoring is in order, but I'd want to see either your models or your CREATE TABLE statements to be sure. (You can paste those into your question, and leave a comment here.)

**Alternatives**

I'd seriously consider running this Rails app on a local machine, writing data to a database on the local machine, especially if you intend to target 200 web servers.  This would eliminate all Heroku row limits, and you don't really need to run it 24 hours a day if this is just a hobby. If you're doing this professionally, your income from it should easily cover the cost of a hobby-basic plan on Heroku. (Currently $9.00/month.) But even then I'd think hard about hosting this locally.

Comment: I've added some information in my post. Good call on not requiring updates to the user account. I have some models on paper, as there are some fields I want to add, but the current models are simple (not sure if you want to see my hypotheticals). There's just some info I don't want to send up with each request, or want to save longer than an hour and display with ease. An example being the last time an update service ran, it could have been three days ago and digging through old updates seems inefficient.